# Goosebumps book where kid thinks his parents have been replaced by aliens

Tags: story-identification, goosebumps

I read this goosebumps book around 10 years ago.

The plot of the story as I recall it is this:
The protagonist - a kid around 10 years old - realises one fine day that his parents are behaving differently from their usual selves and begins to suspect that they have been replaced by shape shifting aliens.
At the end, it is revealed that

> the kid is actually a robot who has turned defective. The parents call the company that manufactures these robots and place a request to repair their "son".

Comment: This reminds me of a very good episode of Deep Space 9 which I won't name so as to avoid spoiling. I wonder if it's a common trope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not Goosebumps, but...

***[My Alien Parents](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/14425052-my-alien-parents)* by R. L. Stine**

[image]

> Ten-year-old Rob thought he knew all there was to know about his parents, but suddenly things have changed. Why do Mom and Dad keep warning him not to ask too many questions? Could aliens from another world really have replaced his parents?

From a review on Goodreads (linked above):

> Well, it ended funny and the start was kinda creepy. That's all there is to it. Rob's a robot, after all. And he was unaware of it...

---

I found this by Googling `goosebumps alien parents` and finding the page for *My Alien Parents* on the [R. L. Stine wikia](http://stine.wikia.com/wiki/My_Alien_Parents), then Googling `rl stine my alien parents robot` and finding the Goodreads review.

Comment: Yep. That's the one. Thanks! Suppose my memory's rusty for thinking this is a goosebumps book.

Comment: It's understandable, considering R. L. Stine is most famous for his *Goosebumps* series and *My Alien Parents* seems much the same style.